# Reflect Filter-less CS50

Tags: c, cs50, reflect

Currently, I am doing pset4 filter-less, reflect and struggling with the code I wrote. It compiles fine, but the output picture looks exactly like the input picture. I am trying to first store the reflected image in a temporary array and transfer it to the image array. I was unable to find anyone who has tried something similar. This is what I have written so far.

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int i;                              //row
    int j;                              //column for img
    int z;                              //column of tmp img
    RGBTRIPLE tmpi[height][width];      //tmp img
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0, z = width; j > z; j++, z--)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = tmpi[i][z].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tmpi[i][z].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tmpi[i][z].rgbtGreen;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmpi[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            tmpi[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            tmpi[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You first copy your uninitialized `tmpi` array into the original array. That will also fill the `image` array with garbage. Then you copy back without any modifications. That does not make any sense because `tmpi` is not used afterwards at all.

Comment: regarding: `for (j = 0, z = width; j > z; j++, z--)`    `j` is initialixed to b less than `z` so the loop never itterates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

1. You first copy uninitialized memory.

```c
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0, z = width; j > z; j++, z--)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = tmpi[i][z].rgbtRed;
```

The array `tmpi` contains indetermined values as you never assign anything to it.

You first need to copy the array to `tmpi` before you can copy it back.

2. Your limits for the loop are wrong:

```c
        for (j = 0, z = width; j > z; j++, z--)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = tmpi[i][z].rgbtRed;
            ...
```

- Here, `z` may only go up to `width-1`.
- `j>z` is wrong condition. It will never be true.
- Proper condition would be `j<width`.
- Not an error but you don't really need `z`. Just use `width-j-1`
- Also not an error but there is no need to copy each member of a struct. You can just assign the whole struct at once.

A fixed version looks like this:

```c
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int i;                              //row
    int j;                              //column for img

    RGBTRIPLE tmpi[height][width];      //tmp img

    for (i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmpi[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = tmpi[i][width - j - 1];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Or you could even combine the outer loops:

```c
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int i;                              //row
    int j;                              //column for img

    RGBTRIPLE tmpi[height][width];      //tmp img

    for (i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tmpi[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }

        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = tmpi[i][width - j - 1];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Or you could swap the values in place:

```c
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int i;                              //row
    int j;                              //column for img

    for (i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width - j - 1];
            image[i][width - j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Feel free to think about more optimizations, once it is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  About the answer that you submitted, since we are not using variable z, I think it should not be defined and in the second loop where we actually reflect the image in the for (j = 0; j < width; j++, z--) loop, here z-- does not nothing so I believe it should just be, for (j = 0; j < width; j++).

Comment: You are right, it was not optimized for unused stuff. I added 2 more versions.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing the color bytes whereas we need to swap out the pixels here, I suggest making a swap function first like this:

```
void swap (RGBTRIPLE *a, RGBTRIPLE *b)
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Then swap the pixels, as we are swapping halfway make sure to run j for width/2

Here's the code for your reference:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int k = width - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < width/2; j++)
        {
            swap(&image[i][j], &image[i][k]);
            k--;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) /*per column*/
    {
        RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width]; 
        int n = width;
        int j = 0;
        do  /*copy in temp file*/
        {
            temp[i][width - 1] = image[i][j];
            j++;
            width--;
        }
        while (width != 0);
        
        j = 0;
        width = n;
        do
        {
            image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        while (j != width);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35576575)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).